# Material identification

Tags: material-identification

Any idea what material the below leotard is made out of? It is shinier than any material I have seen before, and want to make another bit of clothing partly out of the same material.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

## Metallic Spandex

See some samples at [Google Images](https://www.google.com/search?q=Metallic%20Spandex&rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi485DkjdPiAhUS4OAKHV2_AQIQ_AUIECgB&biw=1854&bih=1136)

[image]